# jQuery width function parameters not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a code found from a post in **stackoverflow** to scroll a division horizontally. I can scroll the div for full width but can't scroll for a specific amount of width.

```js
$("div").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollLeft: $(document).width()
  }, "slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
 
<div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Above code is working!

jQuery documentation says that width() function can get values as parameters but when I try like follows, the scrolling is not working.

```
$("div").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollLeft: $(document).width(50)
  }, "slow");
});
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: you cannot use like that. you should get width and then add ur value.. like `.width() + 100` because `.width()` function returns the width

Comment: Just remove the `$(document).width()` entirely. eg. `scrollLeft: 50`

Comment: And, you can remove `event.preventDefault()` since there is no default behavior from clicking a `div`.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say you can `get` values with parameters. It says that you can `set` values by passing parameters. You don't want to set the `document.width()` here, you just want to scroll by an amount, so simply pass that amount without any mention of `width()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(document).width()` function provide the window width. That means `$(document).width()` is equal to a value. Then you have to replace `$(document).width()` with your value. That's how it work.

```
$("div").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollLeft: "100px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/

```js
$("div").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollLeft: "50px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the construction `$(document).width(50)` is not valid, you can just use a regular number, or the result of calculation instead. For example, these results are valid:

```
$(document).width()
50
$(document).width() - 50
```

Here is an example:

```js
$("div").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollLeft: $(document).width() - 1000
  }, "slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**

Reason why `scrollLeft: $(document).width(50)` didn't work because `$(document).width(50)` is not returning a valid number. (Since it is a setter method.)

**Fixes**

> **.scrollLeft( value )** Is expecting value of type: Number (An integer indicating the new position to set the scroll bar to.)

```
$("div").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var ScrollValue = $(document).width() - 100;
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollLeft: ScrollValue
    }, "slow");
});
```

`ScrollValue` can be calculated accordingly to your requirement and be passed as an integer value.

Hope this solves your problem, For more info., refer: https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/